# Is a random variable that has zero variance random?

Tags: random-variables, variance, constants

A real variable or time series called $x$ has standard deviation equal to $0$. Does it being variance-free, with therefore no uncertainty, mean that it cannot be random?

Given that $x$ is nevertheless reported day-to-day by official sources, are there any other names for $x$ besides calling it a 'constant' or a 'non-random variable' or lest 'discrete variable'?

Comment: It’s like calling a square a rectangle. It’s a random variable that happens to have no uncertainty. That’s fine.

Comment: is it more of a random variable than a discrete variable if all of series $x$'s observations (up to today) are $0.0019$?

Comment: What you want to call it ultimately depends on what you want to do. What do you want to do?

Comment: As you define it, it is a constant.